# Can an array be called as a const pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

this is very basic...but please help me if anybody know about this...
Can an array be called as a const pointer?

Comment: Please rephrase: currently, your question cannot be understood ("call an an"). Provide an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is this a HW question?  What do you mean by const pointer?  It could be at least (e.g.) const char *foo and char *const foo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean "can array be used where a const pointer is expected"? In that case, yes:

```
void f(const int* p)
{
    ...
}

int ar[10];
f(ar); // this works, array is essentially a pointer
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. An array always decays to a pointer when passed as a parameter to a function.

Answer (score 2):

if you are referring to the array's address then YES it will be a constant.